# Equivariant version of Morse theory

Tags: morse-theory, equivariant

Is there some variant on Morse or Morse-Bott theory yielding equivariant (co)homology instead of singular homology?

Any reference/idea would be greatly appreciated.

Crossposted on [StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/829417/60713).

Comment: There is a version of such a theory due mostly to M. Braverman and M. Farber. For a brief summary of it and references see Section 5.1 of the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9904148.pdf

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer to your question is *yes, of course*. The theory has been around at least since the late 60s! See Wasserman's [paper](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/wasser001.pdf)

> A Wasserman. *Equivariant differential topology*, Topology 1969; 8(2):127-150.

I think the first "big application" is due to Atiyah and Bott, who used it to study (what else?) Yang-Mills on surfaces. See the first section of this 90 page [behemoth](http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~xinl/library/papers/math/geometry/Atiyah1983.pdf)

> MF Atiyah and R Bott. *The Yang-Mills equations over Riemann surfaces.* Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London. Series A, Mathematical and Physical Sciences (1983): 523-615.

I personally found the exposition in Section 2 of Hingston's [subsequent paper](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.jdg/1214438424&page=record) to be somewhat cleaner and more transparent:

> N. Hingston. *Equivariant Morse theory and closed geodesics*. Journal of Differential Geometry 19 (1984), no. 1, 85--116.

I'm sure this equivariant Morse theory is in many textbooks by now, but the original papers cover much of what it is and how it is used. There's even a recent [discrete version](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X08006201) for $G$-simplicial complexes due to Freij!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've begun looking at Atiyah and Bott's paper. However, from what I can see from the first pages, they don't define some kind of "equivariant Morse complex", or do they do it later? Or should I start from one of the other papers?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I'd start with Hingston and then chase references, particularly Borel's construction in [10]. The problem with "equivariant Morse complex" is that the obvious quotient might develop singularities, so you have to resort to classifying spaces and blow-ups, with everything working only up-to-homotopy. Section 1.3 of Hingston outlines the basic program, and [10] fills in the gaps.

Comment: Thanks for the really fast answer. I will go look there, then.

Answer (score 4):

If you like a Morse homological treatment, you could also look at the paper of Austin and Braam.

> Austin, D. M.(1-IASP); Braam, P. J.(4-OX)
>   Morse-Bott theory and equivariant cohomology. The Floer memorial volume, 123–183, 
>   Progr. Math., 133, Birkhäuser, Basel, 1995.